# express-jsonschema is giving [object Object] in error response

Tags: node.js, express

I have been using express-jsonschema module from long times as a middleware to my routes ex:

```
router.post('/abc/abcSearch', validate({ body: abcFilterPostSchema.abcFetchPostSchema }), abcApi.searchabcs);
```

and all of a sudden its started giving below error for invalid schema.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>[object Object]</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

earlier I use to get proper json error message with explanation if invalid schema for example negative limit given in schema

```
{
    "statusText": "Bad Request",
    "jsonSchemaValidation": true,
    "validations": {
        "body": [
            {
                "value": -11,
                "property": "request.body.page",
                "messages": [
                    "must have a minimum value of 0"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Not sure what suddenly broke the functionality.

Comment: Maybe you've added some kind off error-handling middleware that returns a html-response instead of a `json`?

Answer (score 0):

Its working now I introduced a middleware check for err condition fro JsonSchemaValidation errors

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    var responseData;
    if (err.name === 'JsonSchemaValidation') {
        logger.error(err.message);
        res.status(400);
        responseData = {
            statusText: 'Bad Request',
            jsonSchemaValidation: true,
            validations: err.validations
        };
        if (req.xhr || req.get('Content-Type') === 'application/json') {
            res.json(responseData);
        }
    } else {
        // pass error to next error middleware handler
        next(err);
    }
});
```